# Filter Custom Listview that implements Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, android-filterable

I am fed up of trying this`Filtering` of the `custom arrayadapter`.I just needs to filter listview based on a the title(i.e the first of 4 textviews),there are total `4 textviews` in a row.
Below is what I tried.

**In the Activity**

```
tso.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

**Custom Adapter Class**

```
public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application> implements Filterable{
   public static List<Application> items;

     List<String> items2;
     ArrayList<String> templist=new ArrayList<String>();
     String temp;

    public  Button btnDelete;
    OrderMainActivity order=new OrderMainActivity();
    protected static final int DIALOG_REMOVE_CALC = 1;
    protected static final int DIALOG_REMOVE_PERSON = 2;
    public AppAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listviewrowlayout, items);
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public List<String> getItems(){
        for(Application p:items)
                {

                temp=p.getCode()+";"+p.getQuantity();
                    items2.add(temp);
                }

        return items2;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
       return myFilter;
   }
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();   
         ArrayList<Application> tempList=new ArrayList<Application>();
         //constraint is the result from text you want to filter against. 
         //objects is your data set you will filter from



         if(constraint != null && items!=null) {
             int length=items.size();
             int i=0;
                while(i<length){
                    Application item=new Application(); //do whatever you wanna do here
                     item=items.get(i);//adding result set output array     


                   if(item.getTitle().toUpperCase().contains((constraint.toString().toUpperCase())))
                   {
                    tempList.add(item);

                   }

                    i++;
                }
                //following two lines is very important
                //as publish result can only take FilterResults objects

                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
          }
          return filterResults;
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
          items = (ArrayList<Application>) results.values;
          if (results.count > 0) {


          notifyDataSetChanged();
          } else {

              notifyDataSetInvalidated();
          } 

      }
     };


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
         final int pos=position;
        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.listviewrowlayout, null);           
        }

        final Application app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {

            TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.row_title);

            TextView tcode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tcode);
            TextView tQty = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tqty);
            TextView tPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tPrice);
           btnDelete=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);


            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    OrderMainActivity.builder.setMessage("delete the item?");
                    OrderMainActivity.builder.setTitle("Delete");

                    OrderMainActivity.builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                // do something after confirm
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             items.remove(pos);

                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                                OrderMainActivity.listSave.remove(pos);
                                if(items.size()==0)
                                {

                                 OrderMainActivity.btnSaveSO.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                        }
                    }); 

                    OrderMainActivity.builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }); 

                    OrderMainActivity.builder.create().show();  

                }
            });

            if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getTitle());

           // titleText.setText(app.getTitle());
            System.out.println(app.getTitle());
            if(tcode != null) {
                //NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                tcode.setText(app.getCode());           
            }
            if(tQty != null) tQty.setText(app.getQuantity());
            if(tPrice != null) tPrice.setText(app.getPrice());

        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

**Problem**:
Its not working,nothing changes in listview as i type in the edittext,but all listview items gets lost on clearing edit text

Comment: hey..!! is there anybody who can help me ??

Comment: And the problem is that...?

Comment: @Luksprog:Its not working,nothing changes in listview as i type in the edittext,but all listview items gets lost on clearing edit text

Comment: Did you used some logs to see what's happening in the filter when you enter some filter text in the `EditText`? Most precisely, if you enter some filter text do you get the correct values in the Filter's `tempList`? It's normal that the list empties when emptying the `EditText` due to that if condition(`if(constraint != null && items!=null) ...`)

Comment: @Luksprog:when I gave a toast message  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "list"+tempList.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  it gave listcom.example.polosyssaleman.Application@b749ecc8

Comment: @Luksprog: this is what i tried   if(item.getTitle().toUpperCase().contains((constraint.toString().toUpperCase())))
                   {
                    tempList.add(item);
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "list"+tempList.get(0),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

Comment: Instead of `tempList.get(0)` just do `item.getTitle()` to see if the right item is added in the while loop. And use a `Log` not a `Toast`.

Comment: @Luksprog:ok let me try..!!

Comment: @Luksprog:yes the right item is added

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49291/discussion-between-sajad-lfc-and-luksprog)